# Customize in Libre Office 4.1 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, libreoffice

I am running Libre Office 4.1 on Ubuntu 13.04 and I would like to make some macros to automate some monotonous tasks. However when I go to the tools drop down menu and select customize nothing happens.

Also when I mouse over Organize Macros the macro selector pops up (without clicking on it) but there is no new macro option

Any help to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools->Options->Advanced in the right pane make sure Enable experimental features as well as Enable Macro recording are selected.

Now if you go back to the Macro menu you will have an option to record Macro.